# In JavaScript, how do I create a SharePoint 2019 (on Premise) publishing page?

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, jsom, 2019, publishing

I am trying to find a way to create (and later update) a SharePoint 2019 publishing page via JavaScript.  There seems to be a lack of documentation specifically directed at SP 2019, but plenty of SP 2013 or SP Online which makes locating instructions quite challenging.

I've tried every solution I could find on this site without success, though again, they weren't meant for 2019.

Here's an example of where I've ended up, though I have been through dozens of iterations using ajax, REST and JSOM.  Apologies for the rough syntax, I'm just trying to make it work and it's been chopped and changed over and over.

```
async function editor_createPublishingPage(pageName, pageContent){
if (!pageContent) {pageContent = "<p>Test: PageContent</p>"} // Just making sure there's something in this property for testing

const context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
const web = context.get_web();
const pagesList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Pages");
const pageLayoutItem = pagesList.getItemById(1);

context.load(web);
context.load(pageLayoutItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(()=>{
    const newPublishingPage = SP.Publishing.PublishingWeb.getPublishingWeb(context,web);
    const pageInfo = new SP.Publishing.PublishingPageInformation()
    pageInfo.set_name(`${pageName}.aspx`);
    pageInfo.set_pageLayoutListItem(pageLayoutItem);
    let newPage = newPublishingPage.addPublishingPage(pageInfo);
    context.load(newPage);
    context.executeQueryAsync(()=>{
        console.log("Complete Query Execution");
    },(err)=>{console.error(err)})

},(err)=>{console.error(err)})
}
```

The 'SP.Publishing' object seems to be the problem as best I can tell.  While it clearly exists, it doesn't seem to have any of the functionality mentioned in the documentation (e.g., 'PublishingWeb' and the 'PublishingPageInformation()' constructor are not available).

I am loading the script via SP.SOD

```
SP.SOD.registerSod("SP.js", "/_layouts/15/SP.js");
```

And then executing with 'executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded' as I have done with various other scripts

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){ 
    editor_createPublishingPage_2(`${filename}-${language.token}`); 
},'SP.js');
```

(Followed of course with 'executeFunc' and 'notifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs' where required)

At this point, I can't tell if I've made a minor error, my entire approach is incorrect, or what I'm trying to do cannot be done.  Would be very grateful for some advice!  Thank you

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that this is for a SharePoint classic publishing site.  I have also seemingly resolved the issue with SP.Publishing.  I was missing a SOD reference:

```
SP.SOD.registerSod("SP.Publishing.js", "/_layouts/15/SP.Publishing.js");
```

But now I'm getting another unspecified error and I am having trouble turning it into something legible.  I've been working with SharePoint for years and it still sometimes makes me feel like a complete novice!
[image: Error Object]

Comment: What type of site are you trying to create the page for? Is it a classic publishing site? or a modern SharePoint communication site?

Comment: It's for a SharePoint classic publishing site, yes.  Apologies, I should have included that in my question.